# inside if() cant call another function

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function addcategory() {
        $this->load->model('product_model');
        $new_category = $this->product_model->add_category($this->input->post());
        if ($new_category) {
            $info = array(
                'message' => 'Data Saved sucess',
                'value' => TRUE
            );
            $this->index($info);//not working
        }
        $this->index($info);//working without $info
    }
```

here i need to call `$this->index($info);` within the `if(){}` but it is not working... however when i put this code outside if() it works but i cant pass `$info` variable via `$this->index($info);`

I call the function(`$this->index($info);`) in side `if` then function not working at all. But if i used function outside `if` its get call but giving an error 'Undefined index: info'.

How to call the `index()` function??

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: What are you getting within `$new_category`

Comment: get the error first by error_get_last();

Comment: i need to call index function to after creating $info array.. no any errors just a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare $info outside the if statement should work.
Then use the index function outside the statement.

```
public function addcategory() {
    $info = null;
    $this->load->model('product_model');
    $new_category = $this->product_model->add_category($this->input->post());
    if ($new_category) {
        $info = array(
            'message' => 'Data Saved sucess',
            'value' => TRUE
        );
    }
    $this->index($info);//working without $info
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1:**

> You can use Redirect method to redirect on index :

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('info', $info);
redirect('/controller_name/index');
```

> And get the info on index method :

```
$info = $this->session->flashdata('info');
```

**Solution2:**

> Add this Remap Function to your controller :

```
public function _remap($method)
{
    if ($method == 'some_method')
    {
        $this->$method();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is not doing anything with the variable $new_category
try.

```
if (isset($new_category) && !empty($new_category)) // check for the existence and value
{

    $info = array(
            'message' => 'Data Saved sucess',
            'value' => TRUE
        );
    $this->index($info);
}
else
{
    $info = array(
            'message' => 'unsuccessful data entry',
            'value' => FALSE
        );
}
```